# Command Line Tools location in Sierra

Tags: xcode, homebrew, xcode-command-line-tools

I just updated to Sierra and installed Xcode 8.2.1 from the Developer Portal.

(Why didn't I use the App Store? Read [here](http://ericasadun.com/2016/03/22/xcode-upgrades-lessons-learned/).)

In the past, to upgrade to new versions of Xcode, I would download both the main `.xip` and the CLT package from the portal, replace Xcode in `/Applications` and then install the tools package. With 8.x, it seems like the `.xip` contains both packages installed as Homebrew doesn't complain about the tools being slightly out of date - `brew doctor`.

However, `brew config` lists the CLT as `N/A`. If there isn't a separate download, how can I find their install location?

```
$ brew config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 1.1.13-19-g55c02ae77
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew.git
HEAD: 55c02ae7747bf05eadec95c91497d06ec3dd2ded
Last commit: 17 hours ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: c1b829f4e31955bc8c9e19227ab7a41e92ab9b77
Core tap last commit: 3 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local/Homebrew
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_BOTTLE_DOMAIN: https://homebrew.bintray.com
CPU: octa-core 64-bit haswell
Homebrew Ruby: 2.0.0-p648
Clang: 8.0 build 800
Git: 2.12.2 => /usr/local/bin/git
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /Users/Chris/.rbenv/shims/ruby => /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/bin/ruby
Java: N/A
macOS: 10.12.3-x86_64
Xcode: 8.2.1
CLT: N/A
X11: N/A
```

Answer (score 0):

Worse, having the CLT for Xcode automatically downloaded and installed on my Macbook Pro on April 26, 2017 causes weird things such as unusable built-in camera.

Built-in camera remains unusable after 3 reboots.

Had to uninstall XCode after that update that said:

```
Command Line Tools (macOS Sierra version 10.12) for Xcode
Version 8.3.  The Command Line Tools enable UNIX-style development...
Installed Apr 26, 2017

Xcode 8.3.2 includes Swift 3.1 and SDKs for iOS 10.3 ...
Installed Apr 20, 2017
```

Then camera starts working again after reboot.